# Ошибка при работе с google maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Пытаюсь реализовать карту в своей активити, но при переходе из категории в активити карта не загружается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Класс MapActivity

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    GoogleMap googleMap;
    private static final double TARGET_LATITUDE = 17.893366;
    private static final double TARGET_LONGITUDE = 19.511868;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        createMapView();
    }

    private void createMapView() {
//        MapsInitializer.initialize(context);
        try {
            if (null == googleMap) {
                ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                        R.id.mapView)).getMapAsync(this);

                if (null == googleMap) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error creating map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException exception) {
            Log.e("mapApp", exception.toString());
        }
    }

    private void addMarker() {
        double lat = TARGET_LATITUDE;
        double lng = TARGET_LONGITUDE;

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(lat, lng))
                .zoom(15)
                .build();
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition);
        googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

        if (null != googleMap) {
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(lat, lng))
                    .title("Mark")
                    .draggable(false)
            );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        this.googleMap = googleMap;
        addMarker();
    }
}
```

До этого была ошибка в самом коде,

> Cannot resolve method `getMap`

В участке кода:

```
try {
    if(null == googleMap){
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.mapView)).getMap();
```

Но я решил заменить `getMap` на `getMapAsync`, а также имплементировать классу `OnMapReadyCallback`. Возможно в этом причина ошибок.

Код `layout` активити:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте следующим образом обозначить Вашу карту с маркером:

Код `layout`:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

В Вашем методе createMapView оставить пока так:

```
    private void createMapView() {
    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

Ну и в методе `onMapReady`:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
            .title("Marker"));
}
```

Перед тем как имплементируете:

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback
```

А также вот вам [ссылка](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map?hl=ru#android) в помощь, надеюсь поможет.

Answer (score 3):

Нужно вызывать addMarker() в методе onMapReady. onMapReady - это метод, который вызывается когда карта готова к использованию. В нем нужно делать начальные настройки, и отрисовку маркеров сделайте в нем. 
Еще вызовите обязательно в методе onCreate метод getMapAsync(this);

Comment: Спасибо за реакцию, маркер появился, но на белом экране, так как не удалось создать карту. Высвечиает toast'ом - Error creating map.
Поясните пожалуйста, где именно указать getMapAsync(this) т.к. в коде у меня уже он есть.

Comment: А Вы sha1 ключ зарегистрировали в google console developer?

Comment: да, вроде как все корректно. В манифесте тоже проставил  ключ.

Comment: Вы в консоли должны предоставить те ключи которыми подписываете релиз сборку, тот которым подписываете дебаг сборку

Comment: Покажите layout, где вы фрагмент карты вставляете

Comment: у меня был один ключ sha1, который и прописал в консоли вместе с названием пакета приложения.
После чего вставил сам ключ в meta-data в манифесте.
Обновил вопрос.

Comment: попробуйте заменить ваш фрагмент с картой на этот<fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

Comment: SupportMapFragment как я понял используется для более ранних API, у меня видимо была какая то проблема с методом addMarker(), так и не понял на самом деле в чём причина, но вот решение выше помогло. Вам также спасибо за внимание к данному вопросу.